# i am using spring boot and trying to connect Apache Phoenix

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting error like
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass

[image: Dependecy]

Getting error
[image: Error i am getting like java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)]

Comment: maybe maven didn't autoimport the dependency - try mvn clean install in terminal?

Comment: Please post code, configuration files and exception messages as **text**, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a bit strange but a ClassNotFoundException can also originate from duplicate class in the classpath.

In your case the PhoenixDriver is contained in the "phoenix-core" and also in the "phoenix-client" dependency. You must choose the most appropriate dependency and delete the other.

Another point, mixing versions of the same library will only lead you to hell. Maven will most of the time take care of this but sometimes won't when the dependencies have different ids.